# Multiple scripts in one script Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two scripts that I am trying to combine into one but the last script I need to wait until the first one executes fully.

Script 1 is performing a certain API call which provides a .txt readout which I need converted to CSV.
Script 2 converts that data to CSV.

I can call them separately but I dont want that, I want them in just one script.

Code 1: This needs to run first.

```
with open('IDTag.txt') as file:
  **Code Removed**
```

Code 2: This needs to wait until Code 1 is 100% done then run.

```
with open('File1.txt', 'r') as infile, open('File1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
   stripped = (line.strip() for line in infile)
   lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   writer.writerows(lines)
```

Both scripts work as I need them to independent of each other, but again, I want them both to live in the same file.
I have tried to look for a straight forward answer to this but have yet to find anything that works. I am still learning Python 3 so I am most likely missing something. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried just putting the second code after the first code in the same file?  What went wrong when you tried that?

Comment: If you don’t need the output as the .txt file why not do the converting to csv all in the one script

Comment: Simply nothing happens to the csv file that is created. The data is present in the txt file, but the csv file is empty. But when ran seperately it does as it is expected to ad converts the txt file to csv perfectly.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to reproduce your issue. Merging scripts is a pretty straightforward approach, so if it does not work for you there is likely some error in your code - which we cannot guess.

Answer (score 1):

[@Reedinationer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448618), [I'll do you one better](https://youtu.be/ZQpWRenGF_w?t=63):

This is how you concatenate the python scripts and save the result to a new python file using python.

```
def read(path):
  f = open(path, "r")
  content = f.read()
  f.close()
  return content

f3 = open("merged.py", "w")
f3.write("{}\n{}".format(read("1.py"), read("2.py")))
f3.close()
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put them one after the other, so long as you are careful to avoid nesting one inside the other. Perhaps you could use two separate `with` statements in the second block? I've never seen syntax like that before so I'm not sure if it's valid (perhaps it is though). I would try:

```
with open('IDTag.txt') as file:
   **Code Removed**

with open('File1.txt', 'r') as infile
    with open('File1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        stripped = (line.strip() for line in infile)
        lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

Although I'm not sure how these are dependent because your second block doesn't use `IDTag.txt` as an input.

Comment: This is just an example, the code for this taking an ID number in one file and plugging that information into an API call, then the data is returned to the txt file, which needs to be converted to CSV. I will try that really quick..... Negative. Did not work. CSV file is still empty.

Comment: @NetworkingCat have you tried to `print(lines)` and make sure that `lines` actually contains information? The part `for line in stripped if line` seems suspect

Comment: The with statement allows using multiple context managers since Python 2.7/3.1.